# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined, React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem, I'm passing (IMO) in the `props` the right way, but I still have that error:

I have these lines of code in my App.js

**This one is working:**

```
           <Route path="/users/:username" 
               render={(props) => <Profile  isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} currentUser={this.state.currentUser} {...props} />}>
           </Route>
```

But this one is not working, while rendering "Ride" I am getting an error

```
        <Route path="/ride/:username" 
          render={(props) => <Ride  isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} currentUser={this.state.currentUser} {...props} />}>
        </Route>
```

*Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined*

```
  43 |    }
  44 |      
  45 |    componentDidMount() {
> 46 |        const username = this.props.match.params.username;
  47 | ^      this.loadUserProfile(username);
  48 |    }
  49 |
```

Even when the code is inside (components) they are the same...

Comment: Check your props, the error says `match` does not have a `params` property, do `console.log(this.props)` what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm providing the solution for your current problem but depending on your purpose probably you want to change your code a little bit. You are getting `undefined` for your `Ride` component because there is an extra render for it. Here:

```
.....
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <h6>Made by Konrad Krukar</h6>
    </div>
    <Ride />   <-------- SEE
</Layout>
....
```

This is in your `App` component. Since it is not wrapped by a `Router` you can't get the desired props. I don't know what is the aim for rendering it but you can use `withRouter` maybe.

Comment: SHAME ON ME, so fkn stupid mistake, thank you :-|
It was for testing (prevois way of making simple app, now i;m makiin it othar way), i forgot deleting it

Comment: No problem. We all do that kind of mistakes :) If my answer is ok for you, consider it accepting, please. If not, you can answer your own question with the proper solution and accept it later.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases check if you wrapped component in `withRouter`

example with redux

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(ComponentName)
);
```

or just a functional component

```
export default withRouter(ComponentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you can try is using the React developer tools (if you aren't already) and see what the props look like. The user above me also suggested logging it in the console, which can also help us figure out what the problem is. Right now, in the applications current state, it can't read the property 'match'.

If I'm reading this correctly, there is no prop called 'match' being passed to your component?

Comment: He is using react-router, the username provided in the URL should be sent automatically to this.props.match.params.username

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/aa84d5302bb3bee44fecb58da8575f71.png
You can see that its passing everything as i want... :(

Comment: Can you add a conditional at the beginning of componentDidMount?
if(this.props.match.params.username) { <your code here> }

if that throws an error, you can do if(typeof this.props.match.params.username !== 'undefined')

Comment: still getting error, the same... idk what is wrong
https://github.com/krukarkonrad/problem
maybe checkout the code